# uname command in cygwin

Tags: linux, windows, cygwin, instruction-set

My computer's cpu is AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 810 Processor that its instruction set is **X86-64**. I know when I use command **uname** in **Linux**, I can see the information of my computer with X86-64 showing. However, when I use the command in cygwin in the **Windows** operating system, it shows that **i686**. Why about this? What does the cygwin do?

The command I use is as following.

```
 uname -a
```

Otherwise, I know the uname.exe is under the path *%cygwin%/bin*. I think it should show the real instruction set whatever it is Linux or Windows. And I think although my Windows OS is 32-bits, the instruction set is as it is. Why i686 which is based on X86?

Comment: Cygwin comes in 2 flavors - 32bit and 64bit. In order to maintain compatibility, it will say that it's 32bit when you run the 32bit version of cygwin.

If you want it to report 64bit, then install the 64bit version of cygwin.

Comment: `uname` doesn't show any information about your processor architecture. It shows your kernel architecture.